# Can we use Pre configured AMI to create AWS EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I am not good at writing a shell script/Bootstrap action for EMR. Can I able to use a preconfigured AMI snapshot for creating the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a preconfigured AMI for EMR. However, there are some restrictions in that you must start with a supported EMR AMI. I have done this many times to create encrypted root volumes for EMR (copying the AMI and enabling encryption).

[Amazon EMR now supports launching clusters with custom Amazon Linux AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/amazon-emr-now-supports-launching-clusters-with-custom-amazon-linux-amis/)